# Remove null or empty values which parsed from json in alert dialog

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter.
I parse values from JSON. And create a list view. When user clicks on the list item I want to show data to the user. Here is my example JSON data :

```
[
    {
        "No": "1",
        "Formula": "AlBr3",
        "Name": "Aliminyum TribromÃ¼r",
        "Molwt": "266.694",
        "Tfp": "370.7",
        "Tb": "528",
        "Tc": "763",
        "Pc": "28.9",
        "Vc": "310",
        "Zc": "0.141",
        "Omega": "0.399",
        "Dipm": "5",
        "CpA": "64.9",
        "CpB": "0.06098",
        "CpC": "-0.00007306",
        "CpD": "2.978E-08",
        "dHf": "-423300",
        "dGf": "-452200",
        "Eq": "0"
    },
    {
        "No": "2",
        "Formula": "AlCl3",
        "Name": "AlÃ¼minyum TriklorÃ¼r",
        "Molwt": "133.341",
        "Tfp": "467",
        "Tc": "620",
        "Pc": "26.3",
        "Vc": "259",
        "Zc": "0.132",
        "Omega": "0.66",
        "Dipm": "2",
        "CpA": "50.54",
        "CpB": "0.1037",
        "CpC": "-0.0001202",
        "CpD": "4.793E-08",
        "dHf": "-584900",
        "dGf": "-570400",
        "Eq": "0",
        "Lden": "1.31",
        "Tden": "473"
    }
```

For example at this json data no:2 doesn't have "Tb" value. I want to hide empty values from alert dialog. Here is my dart code

homepage.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'userDetails.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];
  List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();


  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  Widget _buildUsersList() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _userDetails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
            title: Text(_userDetails[index].Name),
            subtitle: Text(_userDetails[index].Formula),


          onTap: (){
            AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Adı: ' + _userDetails[index].Name),
              content: Text('Formül: ' + _userDetails[index].Formula + '\nTfp: ' + _userDetails[index].Tfp +'\nTb: ' + _userDetails[index].Tb +'\nTc: ' + _userDetails[index].Tc +'\nPc: ' + _userDetails[index].Pc +'\nVc: ' + _userDetails[index].Vc +'\nZc: ' + _userDetails[index].Zc +'\nΩ: ' + _userDetails[index].Omega +'\nDipm: ' + _userDetails[index].Dipm +'\nCpA: ' + _userDetails[index].CpA+'\nCpB: ' + _userDetails[index].CpB +'\nCpC: ' + _userDetails[index].CpC +'\nCpD: ' + _userDetails[index].CpD +'\ndHf: ' + _userDetails[index].dHf +'\ndGf: ' + _userDetails[index].dGf +'\nEq: ' + _userDetails[index].Eq +'\nLden: ' + _userDetails[index].Lden +'\nTden: ' + _userDetails[index].Tden),
              actions: [
              ],
            );
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return alert;
              },
            );

          },
          ),
        );

      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchResults() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _searchResult.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return new Card(
          child: new ListTile(
            leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),

            title: new Text(
                _searchResult[i].Name),
            subtitle: Text(_searchResult[i].Formula),
            onTap: (){
              AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                title: Text(_searchResult[i].Name),
                content: Text('Formül: ' + _searchResult[i].Formula + '\nTfp: ' + _searchResult[i].Tfp +'\nTb: ' + _searchResult[i].Tb +'\nTc: ' + _searchResult[i].Tc +'\nPc: ' + _searchResult[i].Pc +'\nVc: ' + _searchResult[i].Vc +'\nZc: ' + _searchResult[i].Zc +'\nOmega: ' + _searchResult[i].Omega +'\nDipm: ' + _searchResult[i].Dipm +'\nCpA: ' + _searchResult[i].CpA+'\nCpB: ' + _searchResult[i].CpB +'\nCpC: ' + _searchResult[i].CpC +'\nCpD: ' + _searchResult[i].CpD +'\ndHf: ' + _searchResult[i].dHf +'\ndGf: ' + _searchResult[i].dGf +'\nEq: ' + _searchResult[i].Eq +'\nLden: ' + _searchResult[i].Lden +'\nTden: ' + _searchResult[i].Tden),actions: [
                ],
              );
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return alert;
                },
              );
            },

          ),

        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchBox() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
          title: new TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Ara', border: InputBorder.none),
            onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
          ),
          trailing: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
            onPressed: () {
              controller.clear();
              onSearchTextChanged('');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, child: _buildSearchBox()),
        new Expanded(
            child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? _buildSearchResults()
                : _buildUsersList()),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Equation Of State'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.Name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
          userDetail.Formula.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

my userDetails.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

final String url = 'http://ahmetozcan.educationhost.cloud/tablo.json';
class UserDetails {

  final String Name, Formula, profileUrl,No,Molwt,Tfp,Tb,Tc,Pc,Vc,Zc,Omega,Dipm,CpA,CpB,CpC,CpD,dHf,dGf,Eq,Lden,Tden;

  UserDetails({this.No,this.Tfp, this.Tb,this.Tc,this.Pc,this.Vc,this.Zc,this.Omega,this.Dipm,this.CpA,this.CpB,this.CpC,this.CpD,this.dHf,this.dGf,this.Eq,this.Tden,this.Lden,this.Name, this.Formula,this.Molwt, this.profileUrl = 'https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/3NbrfEiECotKyhcUhgPJHbrL7zM=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/2014%2F06%2F02%2Fc0%2Fzuckheadsho.a33d0.jpg'});


  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      No: json['No'] ?? '0',
      Name: json['Name']?? '0',
      Formula: json['Formula']?? '0',
      Molwt: json['Molwt']?? '0',
      Tfp: json['Tfp']?? '0',
      Tb:json['Tb']?? '0',
      Tc:json['Tc']?? '0',
      Pc:json['Pc']?? '0',
      Vc:json['Vc']?? '0',
      Zc:json['Zc']?? '0',
      Omega:json['Omega']?? '0',
      Dipm:json['Dipm']?? '0',
      CpA:json['CpA']?? '0',
      CpB:json['CpB']?? '0',
      CpC:json['CpC']?? '0',
      CpD:json['CpD']?? '0',
      dHf:json['dHf']?? '0',
      dGf:json['dGf']?? '0',
      Eq:json['Eq']?? '0',
      Lden:json['Lden']?? '0',
      Tden:json['Tden']?? '0'
    );
  }
}
```

I used json['Name']?? '0' method but it shows 0 if value is null.

I remove it from here if the value is empty or null:

```
Text('Formül: ' + _searchResult[i].Formula + '\nTfp: ' + _searchResult[i].Tfp +'\nTb: ' + _searchResult[i].Tb +'\nTc: ' + _searchResult[i].Tc +'\nPc: ' + _searchResult[i].Pc +'\nVc: ' + _searchResult[i].Vc +'\nZc: ' + _searchResult[i].Zc +'\nOmega: ' + _searchResult[i].Omega +'\nDipm: ' + _searchResult[i].Dipm +'\nCpA: ' + _searchResult[i].CpA+'\nCpB: ' + _searchResult[i].CpB +'\nCpC: ' + _searchResult[i].CpC +'\nCpD: ' + _searchResult[i].CpD +'\ndHf: ' + _searchResult[i].dHf +'\ndGf: ' + _searchResult[i].dGf +'\nEq: ' + _searchResult[i].Eq +'\nLden: ' + _searchResult[i].Lden +'\nTden: ' + _searchResult[i].Tden),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to so. You defined the default value as '0' in Tb in your model. Your UserDetails model should be like:

```
Tb:json['Tb'],
```

And then, you should check the Tb value is null. Like this:

```
              content: _userDetails[index].Tb != null
                      ? Text('Formül: ' + _userDetails[index].Formula + '\nTfp: ' + _userDetails[index].Tfp +'\nTb: ' + _userDetails[index].Tb +'\nTc: ' + _userDetails[index].Tc +'\nPc: ' + _userDetails[index].Pc +'\nVc: ' + _userDetails[index].Vc +'\nZc: ' + _userDetails[index].Zc +'\nΩ: ' + _userDetails[index].Omega +'\nDipm: ' + _userDetails[index].Dipm +'\nCpA: ' + _userDetails[index].CpA+'\nCpB: ' + _userDetails[index].CpB +'\nCpC: ' + _userDetails[index].CpC +'\nCpD: ' + _userDetails[index].CpD +'\ndHf: ' + _userDetails[index].dHf +'\ndGf: ' + _userDetails[index].dGf +'\nEq: ' + _userDetails[index].Eq +'\nLden: ' + _userDetails[index].Lden +'\nTden: ' + _userDetails[index].Tden)
                      : Text('Formül: ' + _userDetails[index].Formula + '\nTfp: ' + _userDetails[index].Tfp + '\nTc: ' + _userDetails[index].Tc +'\nPc: ' + _userDetails[index].Pc +'\nVc: ' + _userDetails[index].Vc +'\nZc: ' + _userDetails[index].Zc +'\nΩ: ' + _userDetails[index].Omega +'\nDipm: ' + _userDetails[index].Dipm +'\nCpA: ' + _userDetails[index].CpA+'\nCpB: ' + _userDetails[index].CpB +'\nCpC: ' + _userDetails[index].CpC +'\nCpD: ' + _userDetails[index].CpD +'\ndHf: ' + _userDetails[index].dHf +'\ndGf: ' + _userDetails[index].dGf +'\nEq: ' + _userDetails[index].Eq +'\nLden: ' + _userDetails[index].Lden +'\nTden: ' + _userDetails[index].Tden),
```

**EDIT:**

IMHO, there is no easy way without RichText.

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          _userDetails[index].Formula != null ? TextSpan(text: 'Formül: ' + _userDetails[index].Formula,) : null,
          _userDetails[index].Tfp ! = null ? TextSpan(text: '\nTfp: ' + _userDetails[index].Tfp) : null,
          _userDetails[index].Tb != null ? TextSpan(text: '\nTb: ' + _userDetails[index].Tb) : null
        ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: but it isn't only for Tb value. must I do this for every value?

Comment: Ok, then you should prefer RichText widget. It is easier with that.

Comment: I mean that some data dont have Tb value, some ones don't have Tfp value , some one don't have another value etc. so how can I do this? for every items

Comment: I try but not working. content is showing null
[link](https://hizliresim.com/IlzQ7D)
[link2](https://hizliresim.com/qqWHYS)

Comment: Of course you need to remove all '0' from your model. They should be null if there is no data. Like this: Tb:json['Tb']?? null,

Comment: now have different error. [link](https://hizliresim.com/5rkgD1)

Comment: I added you :).